# Help proving a field property

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to prove this part of a theorem: given a field $K$ such that $|K| = p^n$, a subfield $H \subset K$, and $\xi$ a primitive element of $K$; i need to say that $H(\xi) \subseteq K$.

Of course $K$ contains all the polynomial in $H[ \xi ]$.

$\xi$ is a root of the polynomial $x^{|K| - 1} - 1 \in H[x]$, so $\xi$ is a root of a monic factor of $x^{|K| - 1} - 1 \in H[x]$ irreducible in $H[x]$.

Now, i think that i must require also that this monic factor has degree $n$. Is it right? If so, how to prove it?

Comment: No. The degree of the minimal polynomial of $\xi$ over $H$ will depend on what $H$ is, so the degree should be $[K:H]$. But an easier approach to your problem is to use the fact that $K$ is the smallest field containing $\xi$ (follows from the primitivity).

Comment: Probably this comment is wrong because it didn´t take in consideration the primitivity of $\xi$ nor the finiteness of $K$. But if $H[\xi]\subseteq K$ then by minimality of the fraction field also $H(\xi)\subseteq K$. What am I missing?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Okok, i agree about the fact that the degree should be $[K : H]$. But how to prove that it is really $[K : H]$ and not bigger? For the second part, if I undestand well, the fact that $K$ is the smallest field that contains $\xi$ implies that $K \subseteq H(\xi)$, but not the viceversa. Is it correct?

Comment: @Aslan986: You are right in that $K\subseteq H(\xi)$ for the reason that you stated. But also ... $H\subseteq K$ and $\xi\in K$, so what algebraic operations would introduce elements of $H(\xi)$ that are not in $K$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: oh ok! Finally I understood. Thank you.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Since your comment appears to have served as an answer to the OP, perhaps you could post it as one (so as to clear this from the unanswered queue)?

Answer (score 1):

Here we actually have $H(\xi)=K$.

Let $F=\mathbb{F}_p$ be the common prime field of both $H$ and $K$. $K$ is a finite extension of $F$, so all of its elements, $\xi$ in particular, are algebraic over $F$. Therefore $H(\xi)=H[\xi]$.

Because $\xi$ is a primitive element of $K$, we have
$K=F(\xi)=F[\xi]$. Therefore we have the following inclusions
$$
K=F[\xi]\subseteq H[\xi]\subseteq K[\xi]=K.
$$
From this chain of inclusions we can infer the claimed equality.

Comment: Sorry about leaving this hanging. I was half hoping the OP to type up an answer, but forgot to A) urge him, B) check this up afterwards.